# Isometry and harmonic forms

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold. Assume that a finite group $G$ acts on $M$ as isometry. How can one prove that $G$ takes harmonic forms to harmonic forms?

Answer (score 8):

Let $(M,g)$ be an orientable Riemannian manifold. The Hodge Laplacian is defined by $\Delta = d d^* + d^* d$.

The differential $d$ commutes with pullback by an arbitrary smooth function. The codifferential, being dependent on the metric through the Hodge star, commutes with pullback by an isometry. Thus, $\Delta$ commutes with pullback by isometries.

To show that $d^*$ commutes with pullback by isometries, show that the Hodge star $*$ commutes with pullback by orientation **preserving** isometries. This in turn can be checked in the linear setting, on the exterior algebra of an inner product vector space with an orientation for a linear orientation preserving isometry. The codifferential $d^*$ uses the Hodge star twice, so in fact, it commutes with arbitrary isometries, orientation preserving or reversing.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3105542/hodge-star-and-pull-back for an example in the linear setting.